# Change cordova www location

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I'm using a script which is being ran `before_prepare`. The script lints, annotates, minifies, concatenates, creates templates cache for any html template, etc in a cordova - ionic app.

This script is placing all output in a `www-build` folder, sibbling to `www` (but it can be placed wherever is needed):

```
├── www
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── audit
│   │   └── tabs
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── ionic
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── service-worker.js
└── www-build
    ├── all.min.css
    ├── all.min.js
    ├── img
    │   └── logo.png
    ├── index.html
    ├── lib
    │   └── ionic
    └── manifest.json
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell cordova to use this new `www-build` folder at runtime (during cordova prepare) to get all files to copy to platform assets.
Maybe if its not at runtime, is there any static way?

Right now I'm hooking `after_prepare` and deleting the assets cordova prepared and copying the new ones to each platform, but I'm wondering if this is a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Cordova looks in `/www` by default. I don't think this can be changed. Why not just have all your source code in a new directory `/src` and then have your built code placed in `/www`?

```
├── src
│   ├── css
│   │   └── style.css
│   ├── img
│   │   └── logo.png
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── js
│   │   ├── app.js
│   │   ├── audit
│   │   └── tabs
│   ├── lib
│   │   └── ionic
│   ├── manifest.json
│   └── service-worker.js
└── www
    ├── all.min.css
    ├── all.min.js
    ├── img
    │   └── logo.png
    ├── index.html
    ├── lib
    │   └── ionic
    └── manifest.json
```

Comment: Won't it break `phonegap serve`? I mean, if I'm not wrong, `phonegap serve` command takes files from `www/`, so every time a feature is developed then it will need to pass the script again and again to keep `www/` up to date, isn't it? Maybe there is a way to tell `phonegap serve` to look at `src/` folder. Does it exist?

Comment: `phonegap serve --autoreload` enable app refresh on file changes

Comment: The problem is not `autoreload`. The problem is that when some changes are made on `src/`, they have to be moved to `www/` in order to let `phonegap serve` to work, because it reads files from `www/`. Is it possible to make `phonegap serve` read files from `src/`?

Comment: Sorry. I misunderstood. I don't think so. What I've done in my projects is use a taskrunner like gulp to perform all my pre-build steps. Lint, minify, and concat all my code. Then I have a task to move all that output to `/www`. I develop in `/src` and my built code goes to `/www`.

Comment: Thanks, and let me ask, do you use `phonegap serve` to develop and see what are you developing?

Comment: I've used `cordova serve`. More or less the same.

Comment: But I mean, does it work when you make changes to `src/`? Are they automatically displayed in the mobile device? Or do you need to make gulp run again? (or do you have a `gulp watch` or similar)

Comment: You would need to use `gulp watch` to accomplish that.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to reach the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

Following the idea of [@johnborges response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40002543/513570) My solution has been to make the script do the following steps:

### Before prepare:

- Move `www/` to `src/`
- Process `src/` to `www/` (lint, compress, concat, annotate, etc.)

### After prepare:

- Delete `www/`
- Move `src/` back to `www/`

In this way the scripts copied to platform are the processed ones, and it does work with `phonegap serve`.